# Как увеличить цифру использую цикл

Tags: javascript

Помогите пожалуйста, не могу разобраться с циклом в JS.
Сейчас использую вот такой костыль:

```
if (video == 199) {
    if (length < 30) {
        document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = ('$50');
    }
    else if (length < 60) {
        document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = ('$75');
    }
    else if (length < 90) {
        document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = ('$100');
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = ('$125');
    }
}
```

Но мне нужно чтобы изменяя `length` с шагом 30 - `price` увеличивался на 25

Comment: Увеличивать вам надо не цифру а число. Используйте let i=0; for(;i<1000;i++){ if(length<i*30) document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = ('$'+(25+i*25)); }

Comment: document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = ('$' + Number(50 + Math.trunc(length / 30) * 25));

Comment: Да, сглупил, тут же вообще не нужен цикл...

Answer (score 3):

Ну если каждые 30 секунд, тогда нужен `setInterval`

```js
const price = document.getElementById('price');
let priceValue = 0;
setInterval(() => {
    price.innerHTML = `$${priceValue}`;
    priceValue += 25;
}, 300); // в миллисекундах, вам нужно поставить 30000
```

```html
<div id='price'></div>
```

Comment: @H4nteR, не совсем понял к чему это

Comment: Прошу прощения, нервничаю, не правильно описал проблему. Секунды я заданию input type="number", нужно что б с шагом в 30 цир увеличивалась цена на 25

Comment: @H4nteR, я все равно ничего не понял, но в любом случае, вам нужно использовать `setInterval`, второй параметр это кол-во миллисекунд, через которое будет вызвана функция

Comment: есть просто две цифры, изменяя первую 30, 60, 90 и т.д., другая должна изменяться  - 25, 50, 75 и т.д. Сейчас вроде понятней написал(

Comment: @H4nteR ну и в чем проблема? Вам нужно отображать секунды? `setInterval` будет вызываться каждый раз, через определенное время, 30c, 10с, 1мин, что укажете то и будет, а если нужно отображать, ну добавьте еще одну переменную и все

Comment: да забудьте вы про секунды.( я уже ж сказал что неправильно описал задачу в посте. Задача состоит в том что изменяя одну цифру с шагом 30, другая увеличивалась с шагом 25

Comment: @H4nteR обновите тогда вопрос и приведите ожидаемое поведение

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать тернарный оператор. Код получается более компактным, а суть та же.

```
var text = document.getElementById('price').innerHTML;
if (video == 199) {
   length < 30 ? text = '$50' : (length < 60 ? text = '$75' : (length < 90 ? text = '$100' : text = '$125'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, я конечно задал сразу не очень корректно вопрос, спешил.

Подсказали мне такое решение:

```js
var length = 0;
$('#seconds').each(function() {
  length += parseInt($(this).val());
});

var step = 0;
step = ((length / 30) * 25);
document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = ('$' + step);
```

```html
<input type="number" step="30" value="30" id="seconds">
<div id="price"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```